# Computed Custom Property Won't Show on Page in Polymer

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer

I'm trying to get a calculated property on the page in my project, and nothing seems to be working. I'm getting the sum of some values from my Firebase database, and I'm trying to return it as the value of a custom property. I know the function itself works, but it's not showing the returned value. Is there something that I'm not doing correctly, or something I can change? Thanks!

Here's where the value is supposed to be showing (the `countedWords` property):

```
<h1>[[theProject.title]]</h1>
  <p class="lead">[[theProject.author]]</p>
  <p><span>[[theProject.category]]</span> <span>[[theProject.genre]]</span></p>
  <p>Word Count: <span>{{countedWords}}</span> of <span>[[theProject.goal]]</span></p>
```

And here is the property and the function to return the value:

```
properties: {
  ...
  countedWords: {
    type: String,
    computed: '_countedWords(pattern)'
  }
},

_countedWords: function(pattern) {
  // var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  // var project = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf('/'));
  // var projId = project.substring(1);
  var total = 0;
  var keys = [];
  var counts =[];

  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/scenes/' + pattern).orderByChild('wordcount');
  ref.once('value', function(snap) {
    snap.forEach(function(item) {
      var itemVal = item.val();
      keys.push(itemVal);
    });

    for (i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      counts.push(keys[i].wordcount);
    }

    function getSum(total, num) {
        return total + num;
    }

    total = counts.reduce(getSum);
    words = total.toString();
    console.log(words);
    return words;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computed property's function isn't actually returning anything. The `return words` statement returns a value to the callback to `ref.once()` (which actually has no effect) instead of to `_countedWords()`. Since the result of `ref.once()` is async, you'll have to switch from the computed property to an observer on `pattern` that sets `this.countedWords`.

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    pattern: String,
    countedWords: {
      type: Number,
      value: 0
    }
  },

  observers: ['_countedWords(pattern)'],

  _countedWords: function(pattern) {
    // ...
    ref.once('value', function(snap) {
      // ...
      this.countedWords = words;
    }.bind(this));
  },

  // ...
});
```

Comment: I tried this and now 'words' is empty. Now nothing is being counted at all. Logging 'words' does nothing. But 'countedWords' does show up on the page as 0.

Comment: My suggestion above doesn't include changing how you calculate `words`. Do you have a fiddle/codepen that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I just noticed a typo in the `observers` property name (it was incorrectly `observer`), which would not set any intended observers. That might explain why it didn't work for you. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SyrupandSass No problem :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know anything about hash routing, would you? I'm having an issue with getting to the right data when I click links to go to my text editor...

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar. You should ask a new question about it. I'll try to answer if someone else doesn't get to it.